# Is there a problem with my Greedy Algorithm

Tags: c, cs50, greedy

when I try to run my code, the result is:

```
 $ ./prueba
    Your change is...0.41
    your cents is 41
    prueba.c:20:19: runtime error: signed integer overflow: -2147483634 - 25 cannot be represented in type 'int'
```

I don't understand that error with the integer and how to solve it, I need to put a money as a float and calculate how many cents I'll need to pay it, so I multiply the float x100, and try to round it, but no idea why it doesn't work, my code is:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include  <math.h>
int main(void)
{   
    float cash;
    do
    {
        cash = get_float("Your change is...");
    }
    while (cash <= -1);
    cash = cash * (100);
    int cents = roundf(cash); 
    int coins = 0;
    printf("your cents is %i\n",cents);
    do{
    cents = cents - 25;
    coins++;
    }   
    while(cents < 24);
    do{
    cents = cents - 10;
     coins++;
    }
    while( 25 > cents && cents < 9);
    do{
    cents = cents - 5;
     coins++;
    }
    while ( 5 > cents &&  cents < 2);
    do{
        cents = cents - 1;
         coins++;
    }
    while ( 4 >= cents && cents <=1);
    printf("Your change is %i coins\n",coins);
}
```

Btw, this is the "easy" project of CS50 week 1, Cash, thanks if you could help me

Comment: your code is far too complicated.  Generally use integer math is in my answer in the linked answer

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```c
do{
    cents = cents - 25;
    coins++;
}   
while(cents < 24);
```

This is what's called a bottom-tested loop, which means a the condition is only checked after the loop body has been evaluated at least once. (The test is at the bottom or end of the loop.)

What this means for you is that you unconditionally evaluate `cents = cents - 25` even if the amount is less than 25 cents. This is incorrect, as it would make `cents` negative! You need a top-tested loop, one which checks if the loop is entered at all. Simply put, the do-while loop needs to be replaced with a while loop.

But that's not the only problem. The condition under which the loop is entered is incorrect. The loop should be entered as long as the amount is greater than or equal to 25. Entering the loop as long as the amount is less than 24 is completely wrong.

Finally, you might want separate counts for each type of coin.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know that about bottom-tested loops.